# django db query, getting error

Tags: python, django, django-models

here is my model :

```
 class company_profile(models.Model):
       user=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
       company=models.CharField(max_length=200)

      def __unicode__(self):
            return self.company
```

and when i got django shell  i did the following, it worked correctly :

```
  from my_app.models import company_profile
  everything = company_profile.objects.all()
  # this gives me the correct out put of the existing company names ,
```

but when i do the following :

```
  username = company_profile.objects.all().filer(user='rakesh')

  this is the error , that i am getting : 

  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'rakesh'
```

how can i solve this , or is my query wrong.

Comment: Typo: `filer` should be `filter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is wrong. The `user="rakesh"` clause needs to get either a `User` instance or the PK of a `User` instance.

You may mean `filter(user__username='rakesh')` or something, depending on what fields you have on `User`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the answer , its a shame that i sometimes miss basic things